# Eventbrite Multiple API Creation

Tags: api, admin, payment-gateway, eventbrite, ticket-system

I am currently working with a client who would like to use Eventbrite as a ticketing system within their website. The major issue is that there are going to be many different accounts making their own events and I don't believe that's possible with a singular API Key.

We would like to have each company who joins to have access to a separate Eventbrite account, but still be able to have the admin overview all accounts to see sales metrics/what events are being created by whom, etc. The admin also has to be able to charge a fee separate from Eventbrite for each transaction that takes place.

Any advice and/or guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you're lookning for is allowing separate Eventbrite accounts to authenticate against your application. Implementing Eventbrite's OAuth (http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/) will allow individuals to have independent accounts, but will allow your application pull data from authenticated accounts.

To answer the second part of your question:

> The admin also has to be able to charge a fee separate from Eventbrite
>   for each transaction that takes place.

Eventbrite doesn't allow for 3rd parties to put additional fees on top of their service fee.

Answer (score -1):

You're essentially asking this forum to engineer your API for you. We don't do that, we just answer questions. My advice would be to **hire a lead developer who knows what he's doing.**